# Pass multiple values of one td name html tag to another variable then print using PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I am really new to PHP code just a week old. I would like to ask assistance on how am I going to display or print all values(pc51 to pc68) I'm using only one input tag td with only one name from a page to a new php page. However, the output is wrong, it printed out pc68 18times as I want to display pc51 to pc68.

**Page 1: Form page**
//table that displayed with pc51-68

```
$var1 = "pc";

form method='post' action='displayall.php' class='form-horizontal'

echo "table border='2' style='width:100%';

   for ($x=0;$x<9;$x++){

    echo "<tr>";
      for($y=0;$y<2;$y++){
      $pcname=$var1.$a;
      echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$pcname' name='td_a'/>$pcname<td>";
      $a++;
      }
    echo "</tr>";       
    }
echo "input type='submit' name='btnss'"

echo "/table"
```

**Page 2: displayall.php**

```
for ($x=0; $x<18; $x++)
{

echo $_POST['td_a'];

echo "\n";

}
```

Comment: Some tags like table and form were not properly written there as it's not visible when I put the correct syntax when posting it here. There was no error in the syntax but the output itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in here, $pcname=$var1.$a;
what is the variable $a ?.

anyway,
you have to use different name attribute for each field or
array type name like beloved,
try this.

change input field name `td_a` to `td_a[]`

```
echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$pcname' name='td_a[]'/>$pcname<td>";
```

and
 Page 2: displayall.php

```
$data=$_POST['TD_a'];

for ($x=0; $x<18; $x++) {
echo $data[$x];

echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include this declaration.
$a = 51;

I will try your suggestion now. Thank you.

Comment: also,
_Post['td_a'] should be change ad $_POST['td_a']